# USB2.0 Transfer using usb_submit_urb gives kernel panic

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, usb, kernel, linux-device-driver

- **Scenario**

I am building and transferring ethernet packets from application over USB2.0.
Inside the USB class driver, I am issuing a request to send this packets to BULK endpoint using `usb_submit_urb`. My ethernet packet size is 112 bytes. I am able to transfer 8000 packets in ~ 200 msec without considering presentation time.

I am making an `ioctl` call to send packets at a very faster rate say I am making an `ioctl` call after every 3-4 usec. Inside my `ioctl` I am issuing `usb_submit_urb` which is non-blocking call unlike `usb_bulk_msg`.

- **Problem**

If I consider presentation time, the kernel panics and dmesg log reads `kernel panic - not syncing : Fatal exception in interrupt`. For **INFO**: By considering presentation time, packets will wait in hardware device till timestamp_in_packet == hardware time.
I need the learning of how EHCI behaves in such conditions or what can be the status of endpoint queues in such a scenario. I am working on a ETH over USB chip. What is the actual cause of such kernel panics.
Any inputs will help alot.

Comment: I'd suggest you try to find the minimal code to reproduce the problem.  Is it correct that you are writing only userspace code (ie, not matter what you accidentally do, you "shouldn't" be able to cause this?)  You can then rebuild the kernel with extra printk instrumentation in the are of the apparent crash.

Comment: But thats a tedious task. Is there any way I can disable hardware interrupts that happens after the successful submission of urbs. I think in my case the problem is the generation of excessive amount of interrupts and as a result the CPU locks(Hard Lock) (Watchdog thread).

Comment: Excessive interrupts would not necessarily result in a crash. The most likely cause is a bug in your driver.

Comment: I am able to transfer 6,00,000-12,00,000 packets succesfully after calling usb_submit_urb in every 100usec, but after that kernel panics (Dmesg error reads : kernel panic - not syncing : Fatal exception in interrupt). Its like my driver is working fine.

Comment: Well the problem has been debugged. Issue was with the generation of nested interrupts. By using flow control mechanism, the problem got disappeared :)